# react native navigator push undefined crash first route

Tags: navigation, react-native

index.ios.js

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS
            style={styles.navigationContainer}
            initialRoute={{
            title: "Stories",
            component: Stories,
            leftButtonTitle : 'blabla',
            rightButtonTitle : 'Profile',
            onLeftButtonPress: () => {
             // this.blabla()
            },
            onRightButtonPress: () => {
             this.goProfile();
            }
        }} />
    );
}
```

goProfile function

```
goProfile : function  () {
     this.props.navigator.push({
          title: 'Profile',
          component: profilePage,
          leftButtonTitle: 'Home',
      });
},
```

Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
This object props have  only rootTag in object.
Why crash on the first page application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `navigator` reference:

`ref="navigator"`

And pushing to refs instead of props:

```
goProfile : function  () {
     this.refs.navigator.push({
          title: 'Profile',
          component: profilePage,
          leftButtonTitle: 'Home',
      });
},
```

So, your NavigatorIOS should look like this:

```
<NavigatorIOS
    ref="navigator"
    style={styles.navigationContainer}
    initialRoute={{
    title: "Stories",
    component: Stories,
    leftButtonTitle : 'blabla',
    rightButtonTitle : 'Profile',
    onLeftButtonPress: () => {
       // this.blabla()
    },
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
      this.goProfile();
    }
}} />
```